# Accessing GUI elements text( ) from outside the PyQt GUI class

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

Ui_MainWindow are .py files generated by designer and pyuic, I wanted to pass the PyQt GUI elements text values to another file and do some basic operation and return the result.

Parent File

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(742, 515)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 601, 331))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        from textvalues import Valued
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Valued.callingdata)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Title", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Body", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Tag", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Create", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    callingdata(ui)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Child File
From child file I'm trying to get the input text values...

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from blog_tool import Ui_MainWindow

class Valued(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        app = self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def callingdata():
        blog_title  = app.lineEdit.text()
        blog_body   = app.textEdit.toPlainText()
        blog_tag    = app.lineEdit_2.text()
        print "Title\n\t%s\nBody\n\t%s\nTag\n\t%s" % (blog_title, blog_body, blog_tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your example code. The main problem is that you are modifying the GUI module generated by `pyuic`, which you should never be tempted to do. Always import the GUI module into your main application and add all the extra code there.

The other problems are mainly caused by not referencing the widgets from the GUI properly. In your example, these will all become attributes of the `Ui_MainWindow` object you created, so you can acces them via `self.ui`.

I have re-written your non-GUI module below to show you how things should go together. But before you try it, make sure you regenerate your GUI module.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from blog_tool import Ui_MainWindow

class Valued(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.callingdata)

    def callingdata(self):
        blog_title = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        blog_body = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        blog_tag = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        print "Title\n\t%s\nBody\n\t%s\nTag\n\t%s" % (
            blog_title, blog_body, blog_tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Valued()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```